# Повторный ввод команды "php artisan tinker"

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Почему при выходе из интерфейса, открытого с помощью *php artisan tinker* *(выход по сочетанию клавиш `Ctrl+C`, а не по команде `Exit`)*, и при повторном вводе команды **php artisan tinker** консоль просто зависает.

Данные о системе:

- Windows 7
- PHP Version => 7.1.12
- Open Server 5.2.8
- Laravel 5.4

Мой вопрос в том, как это исправить?

Comment: Первый раз слышу про такое, видимо в самом windows проблема или openserver.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan что бы вы мне посоветовали, переустановку фреймворка? Я пробовал откатиться через git, но видимо проблема как раз в папке vendor, и при откате с помощью `git reset --hard a13ac1f0faeac2f3d115a06984ce4cc560fb607c` _(т.е., на конкретный коммит)_ проблема не уходит. Разумеется, не помогает ни рестарт серврера, ни перезагрузка операционной системы.

Comment: Фреймворк тут не при чём, я сказал в чём причина, или переходите на unix систему или выходите корректно, ну или рестартовать каждый раз openserver нужно будет

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan рестарт openserver'а не решает проблемы, и рестарт ОС - тоже. Я теперь вообще не могу запустить этот интерфейс _(я про tinker)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже сталкивался с такой ошибкой - закрыл консоль кликом по крестику, и больше не смог запустить тинкер. Как было сказано в комментариях, проблема не во фреймворке, а в Openserver'е. В моём случае помогла его переустановка. А вообще, вариантов для выхода из тинкера несколько:

- `exit();` *или* `exit;` *или* `Exit`
- `Ctrl + D`
- `Ctrl + C`